# Joining multiple dataframes horizontally

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe

```
val count :Dataframe = spark.sql("select 1,$database_name,$table_name count(*) from $table_name ")
```

Output  :

> 1,stock,T076p,4332

```
val dist_count :Dataframe = spark.sql("1,select distinct count(*) from $table_name")`
```

Output  :

> 4112 or 4332(can be same )

```
val truecount : Dataframe = spark.sql("select 1,count(*) from $table_name where flag =true")`
```

Output  :

> 4330

```
   val Falsecount : DataFrame = spark.sql("select 1,count(*) from $table_name where flag =false")
```

Output  :

> 4332

Question : How do I join above `dataframe` to get the resultant `dataframe` which give me Output.
as the below.

> stock ,T076p, 4332,4332,4330

Here comma is for column separator

P.S - I have added 1 to every `dataframe` so I can use join `dataframes` (so 1 is not mandatory here.)

Answer (score 0):

> **Question** :
>   How do I join above dataframe to get the resultant dataframe which
>   give me o/p as the below.
>
> stock ,T076p, 4332,4332,4330 -Here comma is for column seperator

just check this example. I have mimicked your requirement with dummy dataframes like below.

---

```
package com.examples

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object MultiDFJoin {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local")
      .appName(this.getClass.getName)
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val columns = Array("column1", "column2", "column3", "column4")
    val df1 = (Seq(
      (1, "stock", "T076p", 4332))
      ).toDF(columns: _*).as("first")
    df1.show()
    val df2 = Seq((1, 4332)).toDF(columns.slice(0, 2): _*).as("second")
    df2.show()
    val df3 = Seq((1, 4330)).toDF(columns.slice(0, 2): _*).as("third")
    df3.show()
    val df4 = Seq((1, 4332)).toDF(columns.slice(0, 2): _*).as("four")
    df4.show()
    val finalcsv = df1.join(df2, col("first.column1") === col("second.column1")).selectExpr("first.*", "second.column2")
      .join(df3, Seq("column1")).selectExpr("first.*", "third.column2")
      .join(df4, Seq("column1"))
      .selectExpr("first.*", "third.column2", "four.column2")
      .drop("column1").collect.mkString(",") // this column used for just joining hence dropping
    print(finalcsv)
  }
}
```

Result :

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|column4|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|      1|  stock|  T076p|   4332|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+

+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|      1|   4332|
+-------+-------+

+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|      1|   4330|
+-------+-------+

+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|      1|   4332|
+-------+-------+

[stock,T076p,4332,4330,4332]
```